# Why is the plocate database not updating?

Tags: cron, locate, anacron, updatedb

In one of my computers (C1), the `plocate` database is not updating, see command #2 below, run today 03/21, showing a database last updated on 03/14 (it was manually updated).
The configuration is seemingly the same as in another (C2) where it works.
I am posting the output of commands in C1 that I think relevant.
I don't see why it is not updating, especially considering that:

1. As per item #1 below, daily anacron jobs are executed.
2. As per item #6 below, plocate is in the list of daily jobs to be performed.
3. The output of the same commands in C2 is **exactly** the same, except for item #2 (that is the problem), and item #6 (I don't have `sysstat` in C2).

**What could be tha cause of the problem?**
**What else can I do to track down the problem?**

Output of commands that I think relevant.

1.

```
$ sudo cat /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily
20240321
```

2. 

```
$ ll /var/lib/plocate/plocate.db
-rw-r----- 1 root plocate 17M Mar 14 10:58 /var/lib/plocate/plocate.db
```

3. 

```
$ cat /etc/cron.d/anacron
# /etc/cron.d/anacron: crontab entries for the anacron package

SHELL=/bin/sh

30 7-23 * * *   root    [ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi
```

4. 

```
$ cat /etc/anacrontab
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1       5       cron.daily      run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7       10      cron.weekly     run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly        15      cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

5. 

```
$ cat /etc/crontab
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
# You can also override PATH, but by default, newer versions inherit it from the environment
#PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

6. 

```
$ ll /etc/cron.daily
total 56K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Mar 12 09:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x 149 root root  12K Mar 14 11:17 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  311 Oct  9  2021 0anacron
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  376 Oct 26  2021 apport
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1.5K Apr  8  2022 apt-compat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  384 Nov 19  2019 cracklib-runtime
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  123 Dec  5  2021 dpkg
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  377 Jan 24  2022 logrotate
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1.3K Mar 17  2022 man-db
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  102 Mar 23  2022 .placeholder
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  652 Dec  7  2020 plocate
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  518 Feb  2  2021 sysstat
```

Comment: At least on my 22.04 VM, `/etc/cron.daily/plocate` simply exits on a systemd-based system, and the plocate database appears to be updated by `plocate-updatedb.service` using a timer. Perhaps check `systemctl list-timers plocate-updatedb` ?

Comment: @steeldriver - I think you hit the nail in the head. I will see if `sudo systemctl start plocate-updatedb.timer` helps. If so, I guess you could post this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!